# Probability "at-least" question with large numbers

Tags: probability, statistics

> The mean monthly rent of all 1000 one-bedroom condos for rent is
>   1560 dollars, with a standard deviation of 224 dollars. 67.7% of these condos have
>   monthly rents lower than 1600 dollars
>
> If 64 one-bedroom condos for rent are randomly selected from 1000
>   one-bedroom, what is the probability that at least 25 of the sampled
>   condos cost less than 1600 dollars per month to rent

I'm not entirely sure that I'm approaching this question in the right way. I've checked that it follows an approximately normal distribution (which it does) and I've calculated the standard deviation of the sample and found that the $1600 value is between 1 and 2 standard deviations of the mean (mean = 1560, mean + 1SD =1588, mean +2SD = 1616)

From there though, I'm not sure how to use the 68-95-99.7 rule to determine the probability (if its even possible, I honestly don't know if I'm on the right track with answering this question)

Thanks for any help anyone can give!

Comment: If you approximate each room as independent, and a room can be cheap or expensive, the number of cheap bedrooms out of 64 is a binomial random variable. Did you learn about those?

Comment: I have learned about those. Would I be finding the probability then of when z > (25-n*p)/sqrt(n*q*p)?

Answer (score 1):

We know that the probability of having a condo be cheaper than $\$1600$ is $66.7\%$, and for it being more expensive it is $33.3\%$. The probability of getting $k$ condos costing less than $\$1600$ is $\binom{64}k\cdot0.333^{64-k}\cdot0.667^k$ because the $0.333^{64-k}$ is to show the probability of getting $64-k$ condos costing over $\$1600$, $0.667^k$ is used to find the probability of getting $k$ condos that cost under $\$1600$, and the $\binom{64}k$ is to find the number of possibilities of which these conditions are met (i.e. HHHHHTTTTT and TTTTTHHHHH all have 5 heads, so they would both be counted if we were finding the number of possibilities of getting 5 heads in 10 coin flips). Using Wolfram Alpha, we can show the probability of getting $25$ or over condos costing less than $\$1600$ is $0.9999983$.

Source: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum(binom(64,k)*0.333%5E(64-k)*0.667%5Ek)+from+25+to+64

Comment: You may also just want an estimate, in which case you can approximate the percentage of cheap rooms as a normal random variable.